# newest Gnome installed, but how to access it?

Tags: gnome

I've installed the Gnome desktop and got no error messages.  Now, even after rebooting, there is no option to select it when I login.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you used to an older layout? The desktop selection menu is in the top right now.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/527912/cannot-choose-gnome-fallback-after-unistalling-mate-desktop

Comment: Thanks, @GreenRaccoon23.  You didn't exactly solve my problem, but I got some ideas from the link you provided and that led me in the right direction.  I had had a very complicated Gnome install from another website that included ppa-something and a very time consuming "sudo apt-get upgrade".  I freshly reinstalled 14.04LTS and then "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop" and logout and in and -- WHAM!  There it is!!!  Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :)